# How can I find the length of a segment formed by the shadow of a ladder?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> Roger is an interior designer and one morning he sees that his ladder
>   is making a shadow with respect to the floor in the backyard as
>   indicated in the diagram from below. He's curious and found that the
>   angles formed between the corners are the following: 
>   $\frac{\angle CAB}{2}=\frac{\angle ADC}{2}=\frac{\angle ABC}{3}=\frac{\angle ACD}{8}$. He also notices that $AB=CD$ and $AC=8$. 
>   Find the length of the segment AD which is seen by Roger.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&16\,\text{cm}\\
2.&20\,\text{cm}\\
3.&15\,\text{cm}\\
4.&21\,\text{cm}\\
\end{array}$

I'm not sure exactly what sort of theorem or identity should be used here. I attempted different way to tackle this problem. Can someone help me?.

I'm slow at seeing things in space, so an answer which would help me the most is one which can be detailed the most as possible. This problem belongs to a section of **euclidean geometry**. So I appreciate that an answer could follow an ***euclidean geometry approach and a trigonometrical one*** as well so I can **compare both methods** and see which one is quicker. So can someone help me?.

Comment: 8 cm? That's a small ladder!

Comment: @tomi. I don't know who did proposed this problem. But probably he did not see accurate units.

Comment: answer's 16, will post the answer once i arrive in my office

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja If it could include a drawing that could be very helpful as I'm lost at this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

attach triangle $ABC$ and $ACD$ such that $AB$ coincides with $CD$ and $AC$ coincides with $DA$. like in the picture.

look at the angles, triangle $CA'C'$ is an isosceles triangle. therefore $C'A'=CA'=8$. therefore $A'D'=8+8=16$

i wish i could give more detailed steps but i need to work, hope it is clear and do not hesitate to ask!

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Wish I'd seen that way to overlay the triangles. I was trying to add them together in all kinds of ways, but subtracting is definitely the way forward.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Probably it would have helped better if the drawing was in a similar orientation as in the problem. But if I get what you intended to do was to superimpose one triangle over the other. But I think the labeling is wrong. If you look at $B,C'$ It is confusing shouldn't it be $B,C$ and the other point be $C'$?. The second part is not very intuitive. **How** exactly do I get the conclusion $CDC'$ is isosceles?. This proof it looks incomplete to me. Perhaps can you do explain it better, please?. Thank you for your effort in drawing though. :)

Comment: @tomi I still can't see from his drawing **why** the triangle is isosceles, perhaps did you spot it? other than just guessing from the interpretation of the sides in the triangle due the scaling in the drawing.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell my intention with the labeling is, those without accent is from triangle $ABC$ and with accent is from triangle $ACD$. look at the angle, $\angle A'C'C = \angle A'CC' = \frac{5x}{2}$ isosceles right

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja The problem is the letter $C'$ is a bit misleading. Because what it was originally $C$ becomes $C'$ this is where I was stuck **but** your last assertion I dont get it. **Why** $\angle A'C'C = \angle A'CC'=\frac{5x}{2}$ ? How do you prove that?, sorry **I am still stuck there** Help please? :(

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell sum of angles in triangle is $180$. now check triangle $A'C'C$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Let alpha be the angle on $A'C'C$ then $\alpha+180-5x+\frac{5x}{2}=180$ hence $\alpha=\frac{5x}{2}$ therefore it is isosceles. Now that makes sense but **why** you did not added this? In euclidean geometry these things aren't intuitive. I voice my opinion that you should add this to be part of your answer.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell i told u i wish i could provide detailed answer, but i am working^^

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja By the way nice drawing and calligraphy you have there. It looks like my instructor's. Thanks! I am accepting it.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Howdy! I'm revisiting this question. Perhaps does it exist another way to approach this answer without unattaching the shadow below the ladder?. Or is it necessary in all such these situations to "disconnect" one figure to append it to the congruent side?. I have to note that this figure is in $3D$ I mean the two objects are in different planes, does this condition means that the only way to solve it using euclidean geometry postulates is to append figures one next to each other?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell there could be other solutions but unfortunately I do not know any other than this :)

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\angle CAB}{2}=\frac{\angle ADC}{2} \Rightarrow \angle CAB=\angle ADC$. Let's call this $x$

$\frac{\angle CAB}{2}=\frac{\angle ABC}{3} \Rightarrow \frac{3 \angle CAB}{2}=\angle ABC \Rightarrow \angle ABC = \frac {3x}2$

$\frac{\angle CAB}{2}=\frac{\angle ACD}{8} \Rightarrow 4 \angle CAB=\angle ACD \Rightarrow \angle ACD=4x$

I've added that information and the information about the lengths to a diagram here:

[image]

Sine Rule applied to triangle ABC gives us $\frac{\sin (\frac {3x}{2})}{8}=\frac{\sin (180^{\circ}-\frac {5x}{2})}{AB} \Rightarrow \frac{AB}{8}=\frac{\sin (180^{\circ}-\frac {5x}{2})}{\sin (\frac {3x}{2})}$

Sine Rule applied to triangle ADC gives us $\frac{\sin x}{8}=\frac{\sin (180^{\circ}-5x)}{AB} \Rightarrow \frac{AB}{8}=\frac{\sin (180^{\circ}-5x)}{\sin x}$

Equating these and using the fact that $\sin (180^{\circ}-\theta)=\sin \theta$ gives us:

$\frac{\sin (\frac {5x}{2})}{\sin (\frac {3x}{2})}=\frac{\sin 5x}{\sin x}$

Let $\frac x2=y$ to give:

$\frac{\sin (5y)}{\sin (3y)}=\frac{\sin (10y)}{\sin (2y)}$

Maybe that's a way forward?

Comment: It doesn't look much different from what I tried in my notes, but I'm struggling from what to do from here?. Are we in front of congruence or similarity?.

Comment: @amd I don't think we can assume that.

Comment: Exactly. I think we have to use the Sine Rule in both triangles.

Comment: @tomi I do feel that this problem is still not yet solved.

Comment: I need to go to bed! Over to you, @amd

Comment: @tomi This approach seems a bit incomplete. In the last row in your attempt what should be done next? Equate the arguments in the trigonometrical function?. It does not compute!. Sorry I don't know how to say it.

Comment: Howdy! I'm revisiting this question. Perhaps does it exist another way to approach this without the necessity to use trigonometry identities and relying only in euclidean postulates?.